# Collapse columns of a data frame into a string tidily

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with column being test item responses (0==incorrect, 1==correct). For analysis in other (non-R) software I have to transform the item response data into strings. The resulting data should look like this:

`24 1111111111111111111111111110111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
    50 1111111111111111111111111101111111111110111110111111111111111111111111111111
   361 1111110111111111011011111110001111001011101110111111101111111101111101111111
   349 1111111111111111111111111110111111110111111101111010011111110111111111111111`

I was able to do this in a loop reading in one row of data at a time, like this:

```
    for(i in 1:nrows) {
        text[i] <- paste(sprintf("%6d", subresp$study_id[i]), paste0(subresp[i, items], collapse=''))
    }
```

where items is a character string containing the 70 column names to be included. It looks like this:

```
> head(items)
[1] "letter_sound1" "letter_sound2" "letter_sound3" "letter_sound4"
[5] "letter_sound5" "letter_sound6"
>
```

(Unfortunately, the column names aren't all named as regularly as in this example.)

This works, but it's slow and clumsy (I have to do this for 12 test levels and 3 forms each), so I want to do it the tidy way. I tried this code:

```
  resp.str <- subresp %>%
        select(items) %>%
        rowwise() %>%
        mutate(resp.str=paste0(subresp[, items], collapse=""))
```

This doesn't work as expected at all. Instead of collapsing the item responses into a string it just puts it all in a string.

```
 $ resp.str             : chr  "c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1"| __truncated__ "c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
```

I tried `quo(items)` and `!!items`, `{{items}}`, `sym(items)`, in all different combinations. Nothing works.

This is very frustrating. I would really appreciate any help.

As requested here is part of the data:

```
structure(list(study_id = c(24, 50, 361, 349, 296), step_name = c("STEP 3", 
"STEP 3", "STEP 3", "STEP 3", "STEP 3"), assessment_id = c(1888537, 
2533870, 2491616, 2266251, 2315116), color = c("Purple", "Purple", 
"Purple", "Purple", "Purple"), letter_sound1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 
1), letter_sound2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), letter_sound3 = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), letter_sound4 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), letter_sound5 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), letter_sound6 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), letter_sound7 = c(1, 
1, 0, 1, 1), letter_sound8 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), letter_sound9 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), letter_sound10 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .Names = c("study_id", 
"step_name", "assessment_id", "color", "letter_sound1", "letter_sound2", 
"letter_sound3", "letter_sound4", "letter_sound5", "letter_sound6", 
"letter_sound7", "letter_sound8", "letter_sound9", "letter_sound10"
))
```

If you read the data structure into a data frame called `foobar`, the character vector `items` can be obtained: `items <- names(foobar)[5:14]`

Comment: Add your data using `dput()`. It will help to be able to respond to your question.

Comment: Take a look at the `str_c` function in the package `stringr`, which is part of `tidyverse`.

Comment: Indeed you'd need to provide us a `dput`. Judging solely from your code it seems you may be after `pmap`, e.g. `subresp %>% mutate(resp.str = pmap(list(subresp[, items]), paste, collapse = ""))`

Comment: As requested I have included part of the data in the OP.
I tried `str_c` but that concatenated the column names, not the contents of the columns with those names. I also tried `pmap` and `apply` but those gave me this error: `Error: Column `resp.str` must be length 1 (the group size), not 76`

Answer (score 0):

Without reproducible example its hard to tell if this works but you could try something along the lines of:

```
apply(cars, 2, paste0, collapse="")
```

Explanation:

```
apply(object, dimension, function, args_for_function)
```

Apply 'paste0' with arguments 'collapse=""' on the 2nd dimension (columns) of 'cars', return a list.